# How to assign a value to public property which accepts integer datatype

Tags: vb.net

In the below code RowHeight is throwing an error. How can I assign the 
 value to RowHeight in the calling component.

**This is calling component code, where I am assaiging values to ReDraw and other because assigning value to these property is straight forward**

```
 Public Const MTXN_SS_TOTALS_ROW As Integer = 1   
 Private Const ROW_HEIGHT As Short = 500
 With sprICSTotalsGrid
        .ReDraw = False
        .DisplayRowHeaders = True
        .DisplayColHeaders = False
        .RowHeight(MTXN_SS_TOTALS_ROW, ROW_HEIGHT)
  end with
```

Below code is RowHeight public property from primary component

```
Public Property RowHeight(ByVal lRow As Integer) As Double
    Get
        Return sprSpread.get_RowHeight(lRow)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Double)
        sprSpread.set_RowHeight(lRow, Value)

    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: What happens if you use `.RowHeight(MTXN_SS_TOTALS_ROW) = ROW_HEIGHT`?

Comment: Your property only has one parameter... RowHeight(MTXN_SS_TOTALS_ROW) = ROW_HEIGHT

Comment: `In the below code RowHeight is throwing an error.`  Always tell us the error.

Comment: Though it's not throwing error, do you think this is the right approach?

Comment: Your first sentence says it's throwing an error.

Comment: If you use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) then Visual Studio will tell you what the problem is and possibly even suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

`RowHeight` is an [**indexed property**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311323/how-to-create-an-indexer-property-in-visual-basic-net-or-in-visual-bas). It acts almost like an array property, where the `Integer` part tells the property which value to update or retrieve. Assign to it as you would assign to an array index, like this:

```
sprICSTotalsGrid.RowHeight(MTXN_SS_TOTALS_ROW) = CDbl(ROW_HEIGHT)
```